# scanf infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf

This program takes the first number in a file and indicates how many numbers are going to be after it, then does various other things with the numbers that follow.

It seems like scanf is causing an infinite loop when trying to read from the file. WHen I run the program not even the check at 1 works

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        int N, a, n;
        int x=0;
        int t=0;
        printf("1"); //Check
        scanf("%d", &N);
        printf("2"); //Check
        int nums[N];
        int i;
        printf("%d", &N);  //Check
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
                scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
                t+=nums[i];

                if (nums[i] > x) x=nums[i];

                if (i=0 || nums[i] < n) n = nums[i];
        }
        a = t/N;   
        printf("Number Processed: \t%d\n", &N);
        printf("Maximum: \t%d\n", &x);
        printf("Minimum: \t%d\n", &n);
        printf("Total: \t%d\n", &t);
        printf("Average: \t%d\n", &a);
}
```

The way i run the program is

```
gcc -lab16
./a.out <in1
```

where in1 is text and has the numbers

```
7
6
-30
90
3903
-934
443
445
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `int nums[N];` - if you want a variable length array - you will probably need to `malloc()` it. Also, try to add `\n` to your "checks".

Comment: When you print for quick-and-dirty tracing, add `\n` at the end to force the flush, otherwise the output will not appear immediately. Make sure that your input file has an end-of-line marker on the last line.

Comment: @amit I never learned about malloc(), what do you mean?
@dasblinkelight you mean something like
`printf("1"); \n` ?

Comment: `printf("%d", &N);` is undefined behaviour, and nothing can be said about the code past this point. Perhaps you want `printf("%d", N);`?

Comment: @JA3N: he means: `printf("1\n");`. [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) is used when you need an array of size that will be known only on run-time, since `N` is unkown to the compiler!

Comment: Stop hazing him about the VLA, this code is completely valid in C99!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (i=0 || nums[i] < n) n = nums[i];
```

you are assigning `i = 0`, so the loop never realy advances! You probably wanted `i == 0`. This is causing the infinite loop.

Other issue: `int nums[N];` - if you want an array of dynamic [determined in run-time] size, you will probably need to [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) it.

**Update**: note that `int nums[N]` is valid in C99, so if your assigment is assuming C99 you should not worry about this issue. Otherwise - `malloc()` will be needed:

```
int* nums = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N)
```

And don't forget to `free(nums)` before the program ends, or you will get memory leak.

Comment: I put the dynamic size in because when I compiled without it, it gave an error saying `array size missing in nums`

Comment: `int nums[N]` is valid in C99, so don't haze him on it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: true, I added it to the answer - but he should make sure his assigment is assuming C99.

Comment: @amit he said he hadn't learned about `malloc()` so I assume he was using C99 :)

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i=0 || nums[i] < n) n = nums[i];
```

This is the culprit. You are making an assignment `i=0` when you should do a comparison :  `i==0`

Your loop goes to infinity because everytime you are i to 0.

Moreover, the code you gave us, gave me an error, because you were creating new variables during runtime.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "stdlib.h"
int main(void) { 
    int N, a, n; 
    int x=0; 
    int t=0; 
    int i; 
    int *nums;

    printf("1"); //Check 
    scanf("%d", &N); 
    printf("2"); //Check 

    nums = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

....

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with this code.

You mistook assignment for comparison:

```
i=0
```

sets `i` to zero. You probably meant

```
i==0
```

which checks whether `i` is equal to zero.

You should check the value returned by `scanf()`. When data read by `scanf()` doesn't fit the format you specified it leaves the data in the buffer and the next call to `scanf()` sees the same data again.

The reason that the first `printf()` doesn't print anything is most likely that you are not printing any newline. Note that on some output devices like terminals output is line-buffered.

You are passing a pointer to a variable to `printf()`, but your format specifies `%d`. You probably meant the variable itself, not a pointer to it.

Also, if you need an array of length dependent on a value known only at runtime, you need to allocate it on the heap, e.g. using `malloc()`.

Comment: For scanf() I don't think there will be wrong input. 

What do you mean passing a pointer to a variable to printf()?

Comment: Adam, Please, upgrade your compiler to a C99-compliant one, as his code is valid in C99.

Comment: You should handle errors and exceptional situations. Well, you're passing pointers as second argument to `printf()` all over the place. Just pass the variable.